# Words with - (dash) in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have string like "DMZ-trust", when I search in elastic it shows result for DMZ and trust but not for complete word "DMZ-trust". Which property defines this behavior in elastic and how to change it.

**EDIT**
Mappings:

```
    {
         "mappings": {
            "policy_rule": {
                "properties": {
                    "display_name": {
                        "index": "analyzed", 
                        "type": "text", 
                        "fields": {
                            "_lowercase": {
                                "type": "text", 
                                "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
                            }, 
                            "_raw": {
                                "index": "not_analyzed", 
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
}}}
```

Query:

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "multi_match":{
                  "query":"DMZ-trust",
                  "fields":[
                     "display_name"
                  ],
                  "type":"cross_fields",
                  "operator":"or"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add mapping and query you are using

Comment: Added. Please check.

Comment: Your field is analysed..do not apply any analysis to it.keep the field untokenized by applying string field type

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti no, with your solution he could not search for DMZ anymore

Comment: @Lupanoide while searching and indexing same analyzer will be used. So "DMZ-trust" will be broken into DMZ and trust while indexing and searching so it should return document. I tried this in ES version 7.* and it is returning a document. Why it is not behaving similarly in version Vaibhav is using?

Comment: You are right, in this case, the query should work. the problem is the mapping definition @Vaibhav should search against policy_rule.display_name and not display_name. But with this solution I can't undestand why this query works for DMZ

Comment: @Vaibhav, can you provide your full mapping? existing mapping has `case_insensitive` custom analyzer and def. of which isn't provided.

Comment: @Vaibhav, did you get a chance to provide mapping